# Time Division and Date Division in mysql

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Here is my two column of my table emp,and I 'm trying to fire 2 separate query in my dynamic web application(servlet,jsp) where Id be able to fetch my data from table;

```
+-------------------------+----------+
| date                    | serialNo |
+-------------------------+----------+
| 2012-11-21 15:14:08.323 |        6 |
| 2012-11-21 12:48:12.067 |        6 |
| 2012-11-21 09:00:16.559 |        8 |
| 2012-11-21 05:24:20.091 |        9 |
| 2012-11-21 01:11:24.413 |        6 |
| 2012-11-21 14:57:28.531 |       11 |
| 2012-11-21 17:04:31.86  |        9 |
| 2012-11-21 19:33:36.259 |       13 |
| 2012-11-21 20:21:40.524 |        9 |
| 2012-11-21 23:00:44.362 |        8 |
| 2012-11-21 00:24:53.613 |       11 |
```

I want to implement

- Divide the time irrespective of date like

  ```
    Time Division   |  Count
  ```

  | 00:00:00 - 05:59:59  |    3
   | 06:00:00 - 11:59:59 |    1

  | 12:00:00 - 17:59:59 |    4

query : `select date count(*) as Count from info where (date between '%00:00:00%' and '%05:59:59%' or date between '%06:00:00%' and '%11:59:59%' or date between '%12:00:00%' and '%17:59:59%') group by date.` :( :(

I found that I'm not at all close :( with my query any of this,so I'm raising this to this forum.Any kind of inputs on this context will be welcome.

Comment: And there I was thinking you wanted to perform mathematical divisions on times :). `GROUP BY` seems to be the solution to your problem.

Comment: actually I want the division in time.

Comment: Please show the query you have already, that might help. Also, for the problem you have, you would want something like `GROUP BY (ROUND(HOUR(dateField) / 6) * 6)`. This is not real code, just the concept...

Comment: I see; have you tried the concept I gave you?

Comment: could you post your concept in the answer in details

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to do the following:

Define a table for intervals, like this

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS steps (
  `name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  initial time NOT NULL,
  final time NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Fill in with name and begin and end of time intervals:

INSERT INTO `steps` (`name`, `initial`, `final`) VALUES
('Int1', '00:00:00', '05:59:59'),
('int2', '06:00:00', '11:59:59'),
('int3', '12:00:00', '17:59:59'),
('int4', '18:00:00', '23:59:59');

(I've create a final interval por events after 17:59:59; if you will need more intervals, correct as needed!...)

Create a table for your data (something like:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `times` (
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `freq` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Fill it with your time data.

Do the final query:
select steps.name,
       count(*)
from steps, times
where (time between steps.initial and steps.final)
group by steps.name

and the results will be as follows:

"Int1","3"
"int2","1"
"int3","4"
"int4","3"

Hope will help!

Comment: I even go through this kind of example on google,but I'm stressing on the query rather than re-creating my table.

Comment: I see... But the problem is how to define intervals when these ones must trigger the counting. I thing you cannot escape from creating a separate table for control proposes. By the way... You need not to re-create your data table; my idea is just to have another table to control.